# express single route, multiple functions

Tags: node.js, express

is there a way to have multiple functions against a single route.

```
app.get('/r1', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hello world 1');
});

app.get('/r1', function(req, res) {
  res.send('hello world 2');
});
```

Reason: Content Negotiation, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation I've different modules based on the accept header in different scopes, so I can't really reach out from one to the other in the router.

Please advise.

Comment: `app.head('/r1', function(...)` for the negotiation?

Comment: not looking for head, actually, just two different module calls for each route,

Comment: What about [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)? You can't really have "2 functions with same name" (think of an API endpoint as a function). You should check headers and determine action based on that, but not with 2 endpoints.

Comment: That's nonsense. How do you expect the interpreter to decide which handler to call when it encounters the `/r1` GET request?

Comment: @marekful just like you could multiple middlewares for a route, here it's multiple functions for a route

Comment: You _can_ chain handlers but cannot define a route twice as the 2nd overwrites the first. Just chain multiple handlers like they were middleware: `app.get('/r1', function(req, res, next) {}, function(req, res, next) {});`

Comment: And you cannot send 2 responses like your code suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can't have multiple functions per routes as you first described, you can do content negotiation inside your route,

Look at `req.is(type)`
http://expressjs.com/api.html

Something along the lines of

```
app.get('/r1', function(req, res) {
  if(req.is('html')) {
    //do your html stuff
    return res.send('It was html')
  }

  if(req.is('json')) {
    //do your json stuff
    return res.send('It was json')
  }

    //wasn't html or json, so send a 406
    res.status(406);
    res.send('Content type not acceptable');
});
```

Alternatively, someone has made a handy little npm package that does the above: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-negotiate

**EDIT**

As per comment, `res.format` can be used on the Accept header:
Please see my previous link

```
app.get('/r1', function(req, res) {

  res.format({
    'text/plain': function(){
      res.send('hey');
    },

    'text/html': function(){
      res.send('<p>hey</p>');
    },

    'application/json': function(){
      res.send({ message: 'hey' });
    },

    'default': function() {
      // log the request and respond with 406
      res.status(406).send('Not Acceptable');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: how do you do negotiation for custom headers like `Accept`

Comment: edited answer. also see here http://runnable.com/UTlPPF-f2W1TAAEb/content-negotiation-using-express-for-node-js

Comment: is there a way like `if(res.format == "application/json"` or should I check `request.headers.accept`

Comment: that's what the above is doing... you *could* check the headers, but why?